# How to activate Gitlab Pages Properly?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I am currently setting up gitlab pages for our internal network. Now I have completed my project and the CI pipeline is working. Now I have gone through all the steps in the gitlab.rb configuration via the gitlab docs but still I can't get gitlab pages to work.

My Gitlab.rb config:

```
gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
gitlab_pages['pages_external_url'] = pages.domain.xyz
gitlab_pages['external_http'] = ['192.168.x.x:80']
gitlab_pages['external_https'] = ['192.168.x.x:443']
gitlab_pages['cert'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/pages.domain.xyz.crt"
gitlab_pages['cert_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/pages.domain.xyz.key"
gitlab_pages['status_uri'] = "/@status"
gitlab_pages['max_connections'] = 0
gitlab_pages['log_format'] = "json"
gitlab_pages['log_verbose'] = true
gitlab_pages['redirect_http'] = true
gitlab_pages['dir'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-pages"
gitlab_pages['log_directory'] = "/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-pages"
gitlab_pages['gitlab_server'] = 'https://gitlab.domain.xyz' # Defaults to external_url
```

My DNS is as follows:

- A record for gitlab instance
- A records for pages.domain.xyz
- Wildcard for *.pages.domain.xyz

When I go to the pages page in my project the page URL is https://user.pages.domain.xyz/project
and this is not how it works I believe.

I hope someone can help me tackle this problem!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working" what are you doing and what is happening (or not happening)?  `the page URL is https://user.pages.domain.xyz/project and this is not how it works I believe.` -- what about this is wrong to you? Seems correct to me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! If that is okay, what can the problem be? 

I have setup the DNS correctly and my Gitlab-ci.yml file is correct and the pipelines are working the right way. 

The thing is I have 'cloned' the gitlab pages vuepress from examples. Then i have setup gitlab runner and setup the DNS.

Comment: I'm asking you! I don't think you have described any problem at all. From your point of view, what is not working? Can you not see the pages project? Or what?

Comment: Sorry then I missunderstood your question. I have checked the DNS again and it is working properly. I have checked the project again and it is working. The problem is that my project is not visible on the URL. I just get an blank page and it is saying that it takes too long to respond.

My Gitlab CI is fine and is deploying the pages I see that in my CI job.

For your perspective: I have copied the vuepress example site and added the gitlab-ci.yml. I have enabled pages as described and set the DNS. also HTTPS is enabled and I have set a valid SSL cert for pages.domain.xyz.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [GitLab 15.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/09/22/gitlab-15-4-released/#getting-started-with-gitlab-pages-just-got-easier) (September 2022) will help:

> ### Getting started with GitLab Pages just got easier
>
> We’ve made it much easier to get started with GitLab Pages. Instead of
> creating configuration files by hand, build them interactively using the
> GitLab UI.
> Just answer a few basic questions on how your app is built,
> and we’ll build the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to get you started.
>
> This is the first time we’re using our new [Pipeline Wizard](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/cicd/pipeline_wizard.html),
> a tool that makes it easy to create `.gitlab-ci.yml` files by building
> them in the GitLab UI.
> You can look forward to more simplified
> onboarding helpers like this one.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_4/create-pages-onboarding.png -- Getting started with GitLab Pages just got easier]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started/pages_ui.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/78276).